# How to check if a field (instance variable) of a class is an instance or basically is an object of another class at runtime?

Tags: generics, runtime, field

I am developing a bank application and have two classes namely Account and Customer.
One of the instance variables of Account class is an object of Customer class.

```
abstract public class Account 
protected float balance;
protected Customer[] C; //second parameter

private static int object_number=600;
public final int account_number;
public String type;
public int no_transactions;
public Date date_of_creation;

    public Account(String s_acc_type, int c_acc_balance,Customer[] *emphasized text*array_cust_obj,int nt)
    {
        object_number++;
        this.account_number=object_number;
        this.type=s_acc_type;
        this.balance=c_acc_balance;
        this.date_of_creation=new Date();
        if(this.type=="Fixed Deposit")
        {
        this.no_transactions=-1;
        }
        this.no_transactions=nt;
        this.C=array_cust_obj;
        System.out.println("Lenght of Passed array: "+C.length);
```

I am writing a generic logger of my own to which I pass an object of type account.

```
Field[] s;
s=obj.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredFields();
```

I know my second parameter i.e. s[1] is a reference array of type Customer.
But how do I check at runtime if this field is of primitive type (int, float) or it is an object?
Please help!!